# Status: Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Here i am using Django 3.0 and Python 3.7.

When i am trying to update the user phone number or email id i am getting this issue.

Here is my views.py:

```
class ClientUserInfoUpdate(CustomAdminMixin, UpdateView):
    model = ClientUser
  
    template_name = "core/user_info_mutiple_edit_form.django.html"
    form_class = ClientUserInfoUpdateForm
    user = None
    methods = None

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("admin_user_update", args=[self.user.pk])

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ClientUserInfoUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        self.user = kwargs['instance']
        self.methods = self.user.get_userinfodata()
        kwargs['user'] = self.user
        kwargs['methods'] = self.methods
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ClientUserInfoUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user'] = self.user
        context['methods'] = self.methods
        context['countries'] = countries_sorted
        for method in ContactInfoMethod.objects.all():
            context['types_' + method.name.lower()] = ContactInfoMethodType.objects.types_by(method.name)
        return context
```

Here is my forms.py:

```
class ClientUserInfoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user = None
    methods = None

    # sort of a copy of fieldsets, but utilising the dynamic capabiliities of the form
    #formsections = []

    new_info = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        self.methods = kwargs.pop('methods')
        super(ClientUserInfoUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.formsections = []

        # auto generate the form based upon self.methods (!!!)
        for dm in self.methods:

            methodtypes = ContactInfoMethodType.objects.types_by(dm['method'].name)
            methodtypes_choices = methodtypes.values_list('pk', 'type__name')

            if(dm['method'].use_dialling_code):
                dialling_code_choices = countries_sorted_with_dial_choices

            i = 1
            methodname = ""
            for info in dm['items']:
                fn = info.dynamic_form_field_name()
                self.fields[fn] = forms.CharField()
                if(dm['method'].name.lower() == "email"):
                    self.fields[fn] = forms.EmailField()

                self.fields[fn].name = fn
                self.fields[fn].verbose_name = dm['method'].name
                self.fields[fn].label = dm['method'].name + " " + str(i)
                self.fields[fn].required = True
                self.fields[fn].initial = info.info
                self.fields[fn].widget.attrs['class'] = 'span2'

                fns = info.dynamic_form_methodtype_select_field_name()

                self.fields[fns] = forms.ChoiceField()
                self.fields[fns].choices = methodtypes_choices
                self.fields[fns].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input-small'
                self.fields[fns].initial = info.methodtype.pk
                self.fields[fns].required = True

                fndc = info.dynamic_form_dialling_code_select_field_name()

                if(dm['method'].use_dialling_code):
                    self.fields[fndc] = forms.ChoiceField()
                    self.fields[fndc].choices = dialling_code_choices
                    self.fields[fndc].widget.attrs['class'] = 'span2'
                    self.fields[fndc].initial = info.dialling_code
                    self.fields[fndc].required = True

                i += 1

                #new_fields.append(self.fields[fn])

            #self.formsections.append({'legend': dm['method'].name, 'fields': new_fields, 'methodname':dm['method'].name})

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        '''
        # e.g.
        {
            'contactinfo_212695_type_id': u'4',
            'contactinfo_249222_type_id': u'1',
            'contactinfo_212695': u'paul@padajo.com',
            'contactinfo_212694': u'07984 820767',
            'contactinfo_249222': u'paul.vidainnovation@gmail.com',
            'contactinfo_212693': u'01908 925111',
            'contactinfo_212694_type_id': u'8',
            'contactinfo_212693_type_id': u'5'
        }
        '''

        # auto generate the form based upon self.methods (!!!)
        for dm in self.methods:
            for info in dm['items']:
                fn = info.dynamic_form_field_name()
                fns = info.dynamic_form_methodtype_select_field_name()

                if(fn not in self.cleaned_data or fns not in self.cleaned_data):
                    raise forms.ValidationError("There is some field data missing")

                info.info = self.cleaned_data[fn]
                info.methodtype_id = self.cleaned_data[fns]

                fndc = info.dynamic_form_dialling_code_select_field_name()
                if(dm['method'].use_dialling_code):
                    info.dialling_code = self.cleaned_data[fndc]

                # do the save later (!!)
                
                self.new_info.append(info)
               
                del cleaned_data[fn]
                del cleaned_data[fns]
                if(dm['method'].use_dialling_code):
                    del cleaned_data[fndc]


        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        
        # technically we're not actually working on this object, so just don't commit any changes to it and return
        obj = super(ClientUserInfoUpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)

        for info in self.new_info:
            print("saving info")
            print(info)
            info.save()

        return obj

    class Meta:
        model = ClientUser
        exclude = ['password', 'client', 'email', 'invitation', 'name', 'role',
                    'last_login', 'minimum_holiday', 'budget_expenses', 'vat']
```

Here is my reference image of how my edit page looks like

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDhJS.png)

How can i edit the details of the user like when i am editing the phone number i am getting this issue.